# I am trying to make a query work on a Sample Movie Database and I cannot pinpoint the error

Tags: mysql, sql, select

So I am trying to run the following query on the sample database found in [here](https://www.databasestar.com/sample-database-movies/).

The query is the following with its description:

```
-- Q12: List the count of top rated movies by genre.

SELECT g.genre_name, COUNT(m.title) AS nr
FROM movies.movie AS m
INNER JOIN movies.movie_genres AS k ON m.movie_id = k .movie_id
INNER JOIN movies.genre AS g ON k.genre_id = g.genre_id
WHERE m.vote_average >= ALL ( SELECT n.vote_average
                              FROM movies.movie AS n
                            )
GROUP BY g.genre_name
ORDER BY nr DESC
```

While I trying to run the code I am getting this error:
[image: Error image]

Personally I tried and couldn't pinpoint the issue at hand.

Comment: Yes, could anyone see why I am getting that error? I cannot pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly. That said, the error message implies that your version doesn't support SELECT inside ALL.

Comment: @ISimion . . . Your approach isn't correct anyway.  You are comparing vote averages to *all* movies, not just movies with the same genre.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thanks for pointing that out, haven't seen it like that since you pointed out, I guess the approach is not the correct one, but still, I am trying to figure it out in the end.